# Python : How to change from a like impulse list to a like saw tooth list

Tags: python, list, iterator

I want to change the list from like impulse to like saw tooth.
Please tell me how to write it by a effective way.

```
# input list
list_a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

# output list
list_b = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 1.0, 0.9]
```

## Normal code

I want to know how to write a effective way of the under code.
like a list comprehension.

```
list_b = []
for i, val in enumerate(list_a):
    if i == 0:
        list_b.append(val)
    elif val == 1:
        list_b.append(float(val))
    elif list_b[-1] >= 0.1:
        list_b.append(list_b[-1] - 0.1)
    else:
        # list_b is not subtract under zero 
        list_b.append(0.0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "like impulse" and "like sawtooth"?

Comment: Tbh, I like your approach. I would start with `list_b = [list_a[0]]
for val in list_a[1:]: if val == 1:` and use `round(list_b[-1] - 0.1, 1)` to get rid of float point inaccuracies, but otherwise I wouldn't change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
list_a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
new_data = list(map(lambda x:x[-1], [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(list_a, key=lambda x:x == 1)]))
final_data = map(float, list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list(map(lambda x:0.0 if x < 0 else x, [1-(0.1*c) for c in range(1, len(a)+1)])) if a[0] == 0 and new_data[i-1][0] == 1 and i > 0 else a for i, a in enumerate(new_data)])))
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 1.0, 0.9]
```

Comment: Do you like cramming everything in a single line at the gross expense of readability?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I do agree with you but i think this is what OP demanded.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ this solution is not crammed into a single line nor is it unreadable. Moreover, as GarbageCollector pointed out, the OP himself desired a list comprehension, "effective way of the under code. like a list comprehension"

Comment: I could not read it. And sometimes, giving the OP what they _want_ isn't always the best course of action, unless you're only answering for points.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I believe it is best to tailor the solution to make it relatable to the OP.

Comment: I disagree. The goal of this site isn't to help _only_ OP. By answering questions, you and I are building a collective knowledge base for users in the future to benefit from. Being a Proponent of bad practices in the hallowed name of OP is counterproductive here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am not entirely sure it is bad practice to merely to show a shorter solution to a problem, perhaps utilizing more esoteric builtins. If the problem comes down to a more lengthy explanation, I am happy to provide that.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. This processing is a small part of the system. So, I want to rewrite the processing to a effective code. I think a readable is important, but I did not want to time for the processing. Your answer is what I want.

Comment: @HiroyukiTaniichi glad to help!

Comment: If your answer had a semblance of "what you're doing is good enough, one liners are overrated", I'd have been the first to upvote. Well, get the tick, lose the vote, it's up to you.

Comment: I timed both versions and the OP loop takes in my Python 3 setting only a third of the time in comparison to this itertools version.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ perhaps you would like to add an answer of your own preferred nature, so both options are available to the OP.